# Sets in LINGO Programming

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, lindo

I need help on Lingo programming.I have a mixed integer programming to solve it using sets in Lingo.One of the constraints is:

```
S(i,k,w) >= m(i,j) * X(i,t), for i=1,...,I; j=1,...,J; t=1,..,T; k=t+K(j,w)-1,..,t+K(j,w)+S(j)-2; w=1,..,W.
```

Here m(i,j), K(j,w) and S(j) are parameters.The problem is i do not know how to enter index k using sets in Lingo.Any help would be highly appreciated.